# Is it possible to make a custom loss function with additional preprocessing of y_pred?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I am having a trouble making a custom loss functions in Keras.

In our model, the size of the final layer (`y_pred`) is [32, 365], which regards as quantized rates for next 365 timeframes.

I would like to make a custom loss function, which includes both cross entropy and RMSE. So the operations require 1) additional preprocessing of `y_pred` to generate a [32, 1] size logits to calculate a cross entropy with the binary labels `(y_true)`, and 2) another preprocessing of `y_pred` to generate additional [32, 1] values to calculate RMSE with numeric labels.

As far as I know, `y_true` and `y_pred` should have a same dimension in Keras custom loss function. But in my case, the size of the `y_pred` is [32, 365]. Should I either make the dimension of y_true as [32, 365] or add above-mentioned preprocessing steps into the Keras model before calculating two losses?

In my previous solution, I made a custom loss function in this way, but now I doubt that the dimension of y_true is [32, 2]. If the dimension is [32, 365] what would be the data values???

```py
def losses(y_true, y_pred):
    a = 0.2
    loss1 = rmse_loss(y_true, preprocess1(y_pred))
    loss2 = ce_loss(y_true,  preprocess2(y_pred))
    loss = 0.2*loss1 + 0.8*loss2
    return loss
```

**Additional Info:**
The output of the `train_generator` is a tuple of sizes [32, 10], [32, 2], where 32 is a mini-batch size, and 10 is a number of covariates, and 2 is a number of labels (binary, numeric)

```py
train_data = self.train_data_generator()
ntd = next(train_data)
print(ntd[0].shape, ntd[1].shape)
>>> [32, 10], [32, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to perform the operations in the model itself. This way, you would have a model with two outputs and you can apply a loss function separately on each of them, with their own labels and loss weights:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

# the model definition goes here...

out1 = Lambda(preprocess1)(final_out) # you can also implement this using existing layers
out2 = Lambda(preprocess2)(final_out)

model = Model(inp, [out1, out2])

model.compile(loss=[rmse_loss, ce_loss], loss_weights=[0.2, 0.8], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I tried to avoid including the operations in the model since those operations are post-ops and do not need any trainable weights. By the way, would you like to explain how labels from data generator flow through y_true in your example?

Comment: @SUNDONG Having no trainable weights is not a good reason to not include them in the model. Actually, if you are using TensorFlow as the backend, then the separation of model and loss does not make sense as we only have one computational graph containing and computing all the things. As for the labels, you should adjust the definition of generator to return a tuple such that the second element of the tuple is a **list** of **two arrays** corresponding to the two output layers.